# Web3: My deployment gets stuck over Test Eth Network. [Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt: with contract.deploy()]

Tags: deployment, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I trying to deploy my contract using node. I am following a youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oaJynB0nKc&list=PLzb46hGUzitDd39YzB1YvZqeIXXtmBrHX&index=26.

I'm following everything according to this tutorial but every time I run "node deploy.js", I either get timeout error: (Note I am not using any truffle framework yet.)

```
process["on"]("unhandledRejection", function (reason) { throw reason; });
                                                            ^

Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:
{}
    at Object._fireError (C:\Users\schit\Desktop\Solidity Dapp\inbox\node_modules\web3-utils\lib\index.js:49:17)
    at C:\Users\schit\Desktop\Solidity Dapp\inbox\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:246:23
```

My code is as follows:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const interface = require('./compile.js');

let abi = interface.abi;
let bytecode = interface.bytecode;

var mnemonic = '12-word mnemonic';
var endpoint = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<key>';


const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: {
      phrase: mnemonic
    },
    providerOrUrl: endpoint
  });

console.log('********DEBUG*LOG**********2');
const options = {
  transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1
};
const web3 = new Web3(provider, null, options);

console.log('********DEBUG*LOG**********3')

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    var balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    console.log('Account balance: ', web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
    

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
    **const result = await contract
                   .deploy({data: '0x' + bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!']})
                   .send({from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'})
                   .on ('error', console.error)
                   .on ('transactionHash', console.log)      
                   .on ('receipt', console.log);**     
 
    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
  
};

deploy();
```

Comment: You said you either timeout, but never mention the alternative. Does it sometime throw an error? If so, do you have more details?

Comment: Hi! This is the error : Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:

Comment: Hi! This is the error : 
Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt. Or either does not show any error. I think it might have to do with infura but I am not sure. Contract is deployed but the program does not end and I don't think the deployed contract functions properly.